# Is it possible to create a pure CSS submenu off a menu with a fixed height?

Tags: overflow, submenu, css

I have a vertical menu with some items that have a submenu that appears to the right of that item. This is mostly working fine, but the main menu might have a whole lot of items on it, so I want a max-height on it with a vertical scrollbar.

The problem is that if I set overflow: auto on the main menu, then the submenu no longer displays correctly because it can't overflow the main menu width.

Here's my code with an example at http://jsfiddle.net/FK8p6/. If you remove the overflow: auto from the .menu class, then you can see the submenu working correctly, but of course the main menu isn't displayed correctly any more, then.

#### HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>
    <li>
        Menu 6
        <ul class="menu submenu">
            <li>SubMenu 1</li>
            <li>SubMenu 2</li>
            <li>SubMenu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
.menu
{
    padding: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #99f;
    max-height: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.menu li
{
    border: #ddd 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 24px;
    cursor: default;
}

.menu li:hover
{
    background-color: #d1e7ff;
}

.submenu
{
    max-height: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.menu li:hover .submenu
{
    display: block;
}
```

I know that I could pull the submenu outside of the main menu in the heirarchy, and then use javascript to position it. But then I lose the pure CSS menu and it would also no longer be semantic. I can live with that if I have to, but I'd like to find a better solution if possible.

Comment: Why limit the height? I don't think you can accomplish what you want without js.

Comment: @Elezar If you have a menu that is actually going to be that size, could you consider a different method such as the `<select>` menus many responsive designs employ? From a UX standpoint, this is almost criminal.

Comment: @gSaenz It's either set the height or take a chance that the menu will be taller than the viewport. Since our app's outer frame is always the same size as the viewport, we want to make sure nothing is ever larger than that.

@BG_Insight Can you give an example of a `<select>` menu? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tutorial? I don't think there's any problem with a fixed-height nav bar ...

http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/

Oh darn - vertical menu? Possibly this won't help then.